# What is the internet Bandwidth needed to support 2000 concurrent requests?

Tags: capacity-planning, bandwidth-measuring, concurrency

For one our projects, we need to calculate the internet bandwidth required to support 2000 concurrent requests/per second. Following is the scenario detail:

- If 1 user accesses the page, the response page size comes around 8 KB/Second
- So if we have to support 2000 concurrent request, the 2000 x 8 KB = 16000 KB/Second would have to be supported.
- If I convert 16000 KB into Mbps, it comes to 128 Mbps

So my question is: do I really need 128 Mbps internet bandwidth? Or is there something wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 2):

A lot is wrong.

- You assume no compression. Depending on the data that can be extremely hugh.
- You assume this has to be YOUR bandwidth - i.e. it is all dynamically generated and there is no way to offload some of the bandwith to a CDN to serve static content, images etc.

Your request is "off" (as in: unusual) in that you calculate a request as KB/Second - this seems to assume an ongoing connection (i.e. streaming information for a longer time). If that is the case - compression may or may not work, but generally - yes, you do need bandwidth like this. 128 megabit is not exactly a lot, at least technically.

That said, unless you want spikes to happen I would make sure I am not using mroe than 60% of my b andwidth - which would put that in a 200mbit pipe. Still no problem as I have no problem getting a 1gigabit link on a server. This is 2015.

Comment: Hey TomTom, Thanks for your prompt reply. We are already compressing the content and I don't see any content(image/css/javascript) which is static and has a huge size which can be delivered through the CDN.

Comment: Then yes, you better have around 200 to 250 bandwith ready for that service. This is extremely doable. The financial side will need some consideration - it is not the type of bandwidth you want to give away for free. But it is in no way problematic.

Comment: Right TomTom. Once again thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: "This is _2016_" :) Besides, +1!